# How do I submit args while using Spark Submit?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-submit

I need help in using spark-submit please.

```
 ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 --class Main --jars jars/test.jar firstArgs secondArgs
```

This is my spark command to start spark-submit and run my test.jar Main method.

My test.jar is java file with sample code like

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Hello World, Im testing my patience");
 System.out.println("TEST ! : " + args[0]);
 System.out.println("TESTEST ! : " + args[1]);
}
```

}

this.

so my ideal result should be

TEST ! : firstArgs
TESTEST ! : secondArgs

but, instead i get

```
 DependencyUtils: Local jar /home/me/server/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/firstArgs
```

It seems like when I type my application arguments as

~~ --jars jars/test.jar firstArg secondArg

the spark-submit try to take the firstArg as a jar file instead of as an argument :(

How can I fix my command line to make it disgest my firstArg and secondArg properly ??

I've tried seeing the posts on how to use --application-arguments but all the example codes do not look any different than mine.. (At least in my eyes) I cant seem to find what's the problem in my command line. Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go by this
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Last argument to spark-submit is `jar` (without `--jars`) and then everything onward is the argument to your program.

Try:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 --class Main jars/test.jar firstArgs secondArgs
```

Comment: application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked ! except i'm having another error but at least my args are working now thank you lots ! oh i fixed the error with your comment, it works totally fine thank you !